# PDO and classses getting the 'PDOException' error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)' in /home/content/........`

Althought if I do it in one file, it works fine!

My php file:

```
<?php
require 'includes/dbc.php';

$dbc = new dbc();
$db = $dbc->openDb();
$stmt = $dbc->getAllUsers($db);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['iduser'];
}
?>
```

my database class:

```
<?php

class dbc {

    public $dbserver = '';
    public $dbusername = '';
    public $dbpassword = '';
    public $dbname = '';

    function openDb() {

        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbserver . ';dbname=' . $dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $dbusername . '', '' . $dbpassword . '');
        return $db;
    }

    function getAllUsers($db) {
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user");
        return $stmt;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample-code you provided, you're not specifying a database, user, password or host to the database connection string:

```
function openDb() {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbserver . ';dbname=' . $dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $dbusername . '', '' . $dbpassword . '');
    return $db;
}
```

With invalid data, your code cannot connect and therefore you're receiving the connection-error.

As they're global to the `dbc` class, you'll need to use `$this` when accessing them (such as `$this->dbserver`). Try updating your code to:

```
function openDb() {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
    return $db;
}
```

* Also, though you may have removed it to post the question, you don't have any of those variables set to actual values either.

Comment: error: `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/content/...../includes/dbc.php on line 12`

Comment: @Andrew You may have mistyped my sample. That error normally occurs from `$this->$var`, which is incorrect; To access the variables, you have to use `$this->var` without the second `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the database settings? I always use the following to connect using the PDO class.

```
/** Define database propperties **/
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost', true);
define('DB_USER', 'user_db', true);
define('DB_PASS', 'yoursuperpass', true);
define('DB_DATA', 'data_www', true); 

$dbInstance = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DB_DATA.';host='.DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$dbInstance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbInstance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```